# When Selecting a decimal value it is not formatting correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table below and when I do a select where I am totaling the Times and Events, one of them is not formatting correctly, even though the temp table is defined as decimal(9,1).

```
DECLARE @mediaTable TABLE
(
    MediaCode varchar(1),
    NumEvents tinyint,
    TotalTime decimal (9, 1),
    AverageTime decimal (9, 1)
)
```

Table Data:

```
MediaCode    NumEvents    TotalTime    AverageTime
A            2            8.0          4.0
B            42           104.0        2.5
C            26           26.2         1.0
D            0            0.0          0.0
E            4            14.0         3.5
F            0            0.0          0.0
G            2            2.5          1.3
H            0            0.0          0.0
I            4            9.0          2.3
J            1            2.0          2.0
L            6            57.5         9.6
M            8            12.0         1.5
N            0            0.0          0.0
P            0            0.0          0.0
S            4            20.0         5.0
T            4            10.0         2.5
V            2            1.5          0.8
W            8            29.0         3.6
X            0            0.0          0.0
```

The query that I am running is:

```
SELECT      SUM(NumEvents) AS [sum],
            SUM(TotalTime) AS [sum],
            SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('A','B','D','E','F','G','I','J','L','M','P','S','T') THEN NumEvents END) AS [sum], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('A','B','D','E','F','G','I','J','L','M','P','S','T') THEN TotalTime END) AS [sum], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('B', 'T') THEN NumEvents / 2 ELSE NumEvents END) AS [sum],
            SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('B', 'T') THEN TotalTime / 2 ELSE TotalTime END) AS [sum] 
    FROM    @mediaTable
```

The query results are:

```
sum    sum    sum    sum    sum    sum
113    295.7  77     239.0  90     238.700000
```

Its that 238.700000 that I can't get to format / display correctly.

The line that is giving me fits is

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('B', 'T') THEN TotalTime / 2 ELSE TotalTime END) AS [sum]
```

I've tried formatting, casting, and converting but it doesn't want to cooperate.  I know it is probably the /2 that is doing it, but I can't figure out how to get around it.  Any Ideas?  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: The type of `SUM` isn't `decimal(9,1)`.

Comment: try `CAST(SUM(...) AS DECIMAL(9,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get fix `scale` then you need to do `cast()` to define `precision` & `scale` with `decimal()` :

```
SELECT . . .,
      CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MediaCode IN ('B', 'T') 
                    THEN TotalTime / 2 ELSE TotalTime 
               END) AS DECIMAL(9, 1) --- will return 238.7
          ) AS [sum]
FROM @mediaTable mt;
```

Answer (score 2):

`CAST()` function will work for you that already said in comment

```
select CAST(238.700000 AS DECIMAL(9,1)) ---it returns 238.7
```

so in your case it would be

```
  CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN MediaCode IN ('B', 'T') THEN TotalTime / 2
    ELSE TotalTime
  END) AS decimal(9, 1))
```